# PHP MVC Routing -> How do I convert uri array elements to a string useful for routing?

Tags: php, arrays, url-routing

**Summary of Issues**

I'm having some minor issues with my routing in an MVC framework that I am making. The code looks like it should work, but somewhere there is something wrong with the way I've split up the requested uri into an array and assigned it to a string variable. I eliminated all of the errors that originally popped up, so I moved on to instancialize the controller and this is what I get:

**Error Log**

```
Class name must be a valid object or a string in /home2/canforce/public_html/index.php on line 23
```

**index.php**

```
//analyze request
$request = new Request(); //breaks up the uri into an array

//routing
$router = new Router(array($request)); //routes the requested uri
$router->route();

//instancialize and execute the controller
$controller = new $router->getController();
$method = $router->getMethod();
$controller->$method();
```

**Request.php**

```
class Request {
public function __construct() {
    //separates the uri into an array
    $uri = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $uri = array_filter($uri);

    //stores the requested controller from the uri
    if($uri[0]!="") {
        $request['controller'] = $uri[0];
    }
    else {
        $request['controller'] = "home";//defaults to home
    }

    //stores the requested method from the uri
    if(isset($uri[1])) {
        $request['method'] = $uri[1];
    }
    else {
        $request['method'] = "index";//defaults to index
    }

    //stores the requested arguments in array form
    $count = count($uri);
    $j=0;
    for($i=2;$i<$count;$i++) {
        $request['args'][j] = $request[i];
        $j++;
    }

    return($request);
    }
}
```

**Router.php**

```
class Router {
private $language = NULL;
private $controller;
private $view;
private $method;
private $args = NULL;
public function __construct($request) { //given the requested uri in array form, stores it in local variables
    $this->controller = $request['controller'];
    $this->method = $request['method'];
    $this->args = $request['args'];
}
public function route() { //put the requested uri into forms we can deal with

}
public function getLanguage() {
    return $this->language;
}   
public function getController() {
    return $this->controller;
}   
public function getView() {
    return $this->view;
}
public function getMethod() {
    return $this->method;
}
public function getArgs() {
    return $this->args;
}
}
```

**Any Help is Appreciated!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is due to the way in which you are trying to assign the properties of `Request` to `Router`.

```
$router = new Router(array($request));
```

Here you have given the Router its argument as an array with one element. The `Request` instance. **You are not casting to an array**. I'm not sure if that was the intent. Because of this you are not able to access the properties of `Request` in array notation (such as `$request['controller]`).

As is, the `Router` would need to be modified so `Router::__construct()` correctly assigns the parameters. e.g.

```
public function __construct($array) 
{
    $request = $array[0]; 
    $this->controller = $request->getController(); // No longer using array notation
    $this->method = $request->getMethod();         // such as $request['method']
    //...
}
```

**OR**

Remove the unneeded array wrapping  the request argument and type hint on the argument in the constructor:

```
$router = new Router($request);

// Router.php
public function __construct(Request $request) 
{
  $this->controller = $request->getController(); // No longer using array notation
  $this->method = $request->getMethod();         // such as $request['method']
  //...
}
```

Also you will need to store a the class name string before you create your new instance:

```
$className = $router->getController();
$controller = new $className;
```

Comment: What is the return value of `$router->getController();`?

Comment: @Aaron See edits, you need to modify the `Router::__construct()` as above

Comment: Is there not a way to send the $request array from Request.php to Router.php? I see how I could get around it easily the way you're saying by simply creating another getController() except in the Request instead of Router, but that would be a bit confusing having the same function names in both Request and Router and this might be a learning experience for me. I really suck at dealing with arrays, is it possible to simply add some line in and the array will work in Router.php??

Answer (score 0):

The array_filter(); function always preserves the array keys.

When used in the above variable, ($uri) created an array where the current request is stored beginning with $uri[1] not $uri[0] - that key still exists; however, it is preserved by the callback.

You can fix this by adding array_merge() to recreate the indexes, which will reset your array and correctly store the controller.

```
//separates the uri into an array
$uri = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$uri = array_merge(array_filter($uri)); // resets array
```

Did that help anything?